# If I make left and right channels of headphone out touched together and send the signal as a mono input to a speaker, will it be safe and working?

Tags: cable, safety

E.g. Imagine I bought a cable which have a 6.35mm mono head x 1 to 3.5mm stereo head x 1, male-to-male. I think it can send from a 6.35mm mono audio out jack to both left & right of a 3.5mm aux-in speaker. If I do the reverse, and plug 3.5mm stereo side into a headphone out jack (stereo), and connect the mono side to a speaker, will it work and is it safe?

Comment: I asked because I'm interested in such cable for speaker output from 6.35mm jack source, and want to know if it can be used in reverse. I don't know why someone think the question is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, if we are talking about an active speaker.  A passive speaker will not produce impressive volume from a headphone output.

3.5mm TRS headphone sockets need to be safe against short-time shorts since the plug itself generates shorts when it is being plugged and unplugged.  Most of them are designed in a manner where they are proof against shorting, by adding an output resistor (a circuit diagram I just happen to have open on my computer shows 47ohm in each channel, another one 26ohm).  That's rather typical and also limits the power you can draw from such an output.

That doesn't mean that specific outputs might not, after all, react in a bad manner to shorting.  But I would have little qualms in depending on it (tying two outputs together cannot really be worse than shorting them since the middle point in the worst case of inverse signals on the channels would still be 0V).  It would be kind of unusual for a headphone output to mind.  It would also be kind of unusual for a passive speaker to deliver a useful volume: you'll need an active speaker/amp to make use of this.

Comment: I found that many people suggest that stereo-to-mono need to be achieved by so called passive summing, which puts a 1k resister on each left and right line before they are joint to the mono's side's tip. (Good explanation here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/549382/350943)
Thus, I assume a no-resistor's mono-to-stereo cable is not suitable for stereo-to-mono output.

Comment: I am still curious what is the most probable result if there is no passive summing and I go stereo to mono: will it be indicated by a distorted sound, or will the result seems like it's working, but in long term may causes demage to some component? And what type of speaker will be worst in this case? (e.g. high/low impedance)

Comment: @JohnnyWong When working from the output circuit, you'll need resistors.  But headphone outputs as well as audio signal outputs generally have output resistors.  So you get what you call "passive summing" anyway (it's actually passive _averaging_ unless you have a very low impedance input compared to the outputs).  The only conceivable exception would be if the headphone output used the speaker output directly, and that would only make sense for very low power amps.